# Adding admin to fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, admin, access-token

I have an app with advanced permission for fanpages.

I was wondering, is there any way possible to add an admin to a fanpage through any API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with regular apps, the app must be whitelisted.

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "message": "(#100) App must be on whitelist",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Graph api for page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

only gives the documentation about fetching admins but there's nothing about adding new admins.

But this should work  (though, it gives me "app should be on whitelist" error)

POST `admin_id` field with valid facebook id to

`https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/admins`,

with a valid page access token (not user access_token)